# String concatenation inside for loop is very slow

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to create xml output then generate excel file, On my loop script it's working on thousand of data but for now I'm having a million data and takes too long and sometimes it hang up, I just want to know if there is any way that I can use to optimize the loop here.

## Usage:

**loop = 10000 works fine**

**loop >= 100000 result too slow and stack**

```
class ExcelHyperlink:
  def __init__(self,sheetName,displayName):
    self.sheetName = sheetName.replace(" ","_")
    self.displayName = displayName
  def toCellString(self):
    sheet = escapeHTML(self.sheetName)
    display = escapeHTML(self.displayName)
    return '<Cell ss:StyleID="s63" ss:HRef="#%s!A1"><Data ss:Type="String">%s</Data></Cell>\n' % (sheet,display)    

def getCellString(value):
  if isinstance(value,ExcelHyperlink):
    return value.toCellString()
  else:
    return "<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">%s</Data></Cell>\n" % (value)

loop = 10000
data = [{u'test': 0, u'a': 0, u'b': 0},{u'test': 1, u'a': 1, u'b': 1},{u'test': 2, u'a': 2, u'b': 2},{u'test': 3, u'a': 3, u'b': 3},{u'test': 4, u'a': 4, u'b': 4}] * loop

headers = ['test', 'a', 'b']


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
</DocumentProperties>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><WindowHeight>600</WindowHeight><WindowWidth>800</WindowWidth><WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX><WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY><ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure><ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows></ExcelWorkbook>
<Styles><Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal"><Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/><Borders/><Font/><Interior/><NumberFormat/><Protection/></Style><Style ss:ID="s21"><NumberFormat ss:Format="General Date"/></Style><Style ss:ID="s63" ss:Name="Hyperlink"><Font ss:Family="Arial" ss:Color="#0563C1" ss:Underline="Single"/></Style><Style ss:ID="s23"><Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/><Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/></Style></Styles>
'''

for row in data:  
  xml += "<Row>\n"
  for item in headers:    
    #xml += str(row)
    xml += getCellString(row[item])
  xml += "</Row>\n"
xml += '''</Table>                
  
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<Selected/>
<Panes></Panes>
<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
</WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
'''
xml += "</Workbook>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in python are *immutable*. All these repeated string addition operations are wasteful, because new memory and objects must be allocated and created, and data copied - at *each iteration*.

I'd suggest putting everything inside a list and calling `str.join` at the end.

```
xml_artefacts = []
for row in data:  
    xml_artefacts.append("<Row>\n")
    for item in headers:    
        xml_artefacts.append(getCellString(row[item]))
    xml_artefacts.append("</Row>\n")

xml_artefacts.append('''</Table>  ...  </Workbook>''')
```

Now, perform concatenation with the `xml` string.

```
xml += ''.join(xml_artefacts)
```